# Escape forward slash for data value in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, escaping

Trying to learn React JS so forgive me if this is common knowledge or the wrong format. Looked on here and haven't found any similar solutions for what I am trying to accomplish. I am also using The Movie Database for my learning project.

What the code currently does:

1. I have a a method that fetches current trending tv shows from this API call:

   const TRENDING_TV_URL = `${API_URL}trending/tv/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
2. From that data, I map it to different components where I want to use it
3. I am pulling from the data that is returned from the API call and putting it as my URL route when a title is clicked
4. I call this value: fetchContentId
5. For example, when clicking "The Boys" title it returns this in my URL "http://localhost:3000/tv/76479"
6. This is exactly what I want.
7. The issue, I have a new API call where I would like to use the fetchContentId value to get the individual title data. To do this I need to know if it is a tv show or movie, then have the id separated by a forward slash. I can pull these values from media_type and id. And believe I am doing so correctly due to the result I get back in my URL. It appears the issue / problem is when I separate the values by forward slash and then send that value to the new API call.

API call I am trying to do: `const endpoint =` ${API_URL}${fetchContentId}?api_key=${API_KEY}`;`
Based on my URL that is using the same value, I should be getting "tv/76479" when passing the `fetchContentId` in.

Question: How would I accomplish something like `fetchContentId={dataId.media_type + "/" + dataId.id}`

I think I need to encode this? But doing `fetchContentId={encodeURIComponent(dataId.media_type + "/" + dataId.id)}` gives me this in my URL when clicking "The Boys" title: http://localhost:3000/tv%2F76479. Not entirely sure how I would decode this either.

```
<Grid header={searchTerm ? "Search Result" : "Trending TV Shows"}>
        {TV_Data.map((dataId) => (
          <Card
            key={dataId.id}
            clickable
            image={
              dataId.poster_path
                ? `${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${POSTER_SIZE}${dataId.poster_path}`
                : NoImage
            }
            voteAverage={dataId.vote_average}
            **fetchContentId={dataId.media_type + "/" + dataId.id}**
          />
        ))}
      </Grid>
```

Comment: If this is being used as a URI parameter then is it practical to have two parameters instead of one?

Comment: `encodeURI(dataId.media_type + "/" + dataId.id)` or `encode(\`${dataId.media_type}/${dataId.id}\``) or just `\`${dataId.media_type}/${dataId.id}\``?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to achieve this. It automatically handles path-name and search parameters.